# How to calculate $\int_0^1e^xdx$ using Riemann sums.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

I need to calculate $\int_0^1 e^x dx$
using Riemann sums. And I'm getting stuck at the point where my intervals are $1/n$ and my final limit is
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n (1/(1-e^{1/n}))$ and at this point I don't really know what to do next.

Comment: Do you mean $\int_0^1 e^x dx$ ? You should write it `$\int_0^1 e^x dx$`...

Comment: yes thats what i meant but i didint know how to put this here

Answer (score 2):

As I interpret your result, you have "recognized" in the Riemann sum :

$$\frac1n\left(e^{\tfrac0n}+e^{\tfrac1n}+e^{\tfrac2n}+\cdots+e^{\tfrac{(n-1)}{n}}\right)$$

the sum of a geometric progression ; indeed, setting $a=e^{\tfrac1n}$, we have

$$S_n=\frac1n(a^0+a^1+a^2\cdots+a^{n-1})$$

*But* at this point, you have considered that you have an *infinite* summation, whereas in fact, we have a finite sum with formula :

$$S_n=\frac1n \frac{a^n-1}{a-1}=\frac{\frac1n}{e^{\tfrac1n}-1}(e-1)$$

The limit of $S_n$ when $n \to \infty$ is $e-1$ (as awaited), using a classical limit. Do you see which one ?

Comment: I have seen that you haven't validated any of the answers given to your questions. It is important to do it  in order that the question is considered as closed (once, of course, you consider you have had "the right answer").